# Given $\log_3 4 = 1.2619$ and $\log_3 5 = 1.4650$ solve $e^x = 176$ to the nearest hundredth

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Given $\log_3 4 = 1.2619$ and $\log_3 5 = 1.4650$, solve $e^x = 176$ to the nearest hundredth.

So I figure you need to express it in terms of $\log_3 4$ and $\log_3 5$, but I can't see how to do it. Either, I have trouble expressing it in terms of log with base 3 or I'm stuck with $e^x$.

$x=\ln 176$, how can I go from this and express it with $\log$ base 3?

Comment: I don't see any particular connection between those values and the desired computation.the given data contains no information about *e*, after all.

Comment: No information about $\log11$, either, as $176=2^4\cdot11$.

Comment: We have $e \approx 272/100 = 2^4\cdot 17/100.$

Comment: I think I can see how to get a good approximation to $\log_3(176)$, but I don't see how to convert that to a natural logarithm.

Comment: Are you given any assumptions about $e$, besides $\ln e = 1$ and $2 < e < 3$?

Comment: I wonder if we are supposed to assume $e\approx 2.7 = \frac{3^3}{10}$ somehow and figure the error will be within a hundred.  ... $e^x= 176; \frac{27}{10}^x \approx 176; 3^{3x}=176\times 10^x; 3x \equiv \log_3 176 + x\log_3 2 + x\log_3 5=\log_3 176 + \frac x2\log_3 4 + x\log_3 5$ and so on.... not sure I'd consider it a problem worth doing and I'm not sure just what the margin of error can be said with certainty to be but... I guess that could work.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I almost got it.  Let $a=\log_3 4$ and $b=\log_3 5$.

$$x = \ln 176 = \frac{\log_3 176}{\log_3 e} \approx \frac{\log_3 \sqrt{3}\cdot 100}{\log_3 27/10} = \frac{1/2+a+2b}{3-a/2-b} = 5.189\ldots.  $$

So within two hundredths, anyway.

Comment: I don't know if this makes things easier or more accurate but instead of figuring $176\approx \sqrt 3\times 100$ we could do $176=16\times 11\approx 16\times \frac {100}9$.  Taking $\log_3$ of that we get $2\log_3 4 + \log_3 4 + 2\log_3 5-\log_3 9= 3a+2b -2$  (and I guess that means $\frac 12+a\approx 3a-2$....)

Comment: ... actually as $100 \sqrt 3 \approx 173.2$ and $16\times {100}9 \approx = 177.7$ I guess that *is* more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Given the expression

$$e^x=176$$

and the expression

$$ \log_3 4 + \log_3 5 = \log_3 20 \approx  2.7269 \approx e $$

So you can write

$${(\log_3 20)}^x=176$$

Comment: I don't see how this helps...

Comment: I also am confused how this helps.  In addition, the problem requires a computation *to the nearest hundreth*.  So, I would be hesitant here because of the discrepancy between $(2.7269)$ and $(2.71828).$  Further, I question whether this represents the problem composer's intent.  This approach seems to assume that the problem solver has already been taught that $\displaystyle ~\log_3(20)~$ is *close* to the value of $(e)$.